# Хочу получить контент сообщения полностью, а не лишь первое слово

Tags: discord, discord.py

пытаюсь сделать типо генератор письма дедушке морозу, но в дискорде. Я не так-уж и силен в Discord.Py в целом. Можете помочь? Пожалуйтса.

Вот небольшой кусочек из моего кода.

```
@bot.command(aliases=['santaclaus', 'дедушкамороз'])
async def дедуморозу(name, age, mesto, chto, xochu, * , ctx):
        await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(
            title=f'Письмо дедушке морозу от {ctx.author}.',
            description=f'Здравствуй Дедушка Мороз ! Меня зовут {name}. \nМне {age}! Не много не мало, но я верю и надеюсь в то, что ты есть и сейчас читаешь моё письмо. Моя мама очень злая тётя. Она не разрешает писать мне письма тебе. \nКогда я её не слушаюсь, она бросает в меня {chto} прямо в {mesto}. Я надеюсь на новый год я найду под ёлочкой {xochu}. \nЕсли ты не прочтёшь это письмо или оно не дойдёт до тебя, мнебудет очень плохо! Помни что я верю в тебя, Дедушка Мороз! \n\nДедушке Морозу, {name}'
        ))
```

Comment: Ну в целом у тебя код был правильный, но вот аргументы в каком порядке расставлены...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как вариант можно сделать это всё в одну строку и просто просплитить,
например:

Вводим: `!дедуморозу name | age | mesto | chto | hochu`

```
@bot.command(aliases=['santaclaus', 'дедушкамороз'])
async def дедуморозу(ctx, *, query):
    query = query.split(' | ')
    name = query[0]
    age = query[1]
    mesto = query[2]
    chto = query[3]
    hochu = query[4]
    await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(
        title=f'Письмо дедушке морозу от {ctx.author}.',
        description=f"""
Здравствуй Дедушка Мороз ! Меня зовут {name}.
Мне {age}! Не много не мало, но я верю и надеюсь в то, что ты есть и сейчас читаешь моё письмо. Моя мама очень злая тётя. Она не разрешает писать мне письма тебе.
Когда я её не слушаюсь, она бросает в меня {chto} прямо в {mesto}. Я надеюсь на новый год я найду под ёлочкой {hochu}.
Если ты не прочтёшь это письмо или оно не дойдёт до тебя, мне будет очень плохо! Помни что я верю в тебя, Дедушка Мороз!

Дедушке Морозу, {name}
"""
    ))
```

Это один из вариантов

Comment: Ох, подождите минутку. Сейчас протестирую на своем боте...

Comment: Ля, братанчик, спасибо большое! Все работает! <3